# How to assign 1 st, 2 nd,3 rd etc based on number in date filed using power bi DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

How to assign automatically st/nd/rd/th to number behind in date field using power bi DAX formula.

I'm creating labels for date something like this `1st MAY 2020`but if we have 2 may then it would be 2nd may likewise, for this how we create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use DAX SWITCH() function to resolve this case like below example

Sub Heading  =

"Status  for" &  " "  & MAX('People Registered'[Last  Refresh Time])  &  " "  &  "JKT"  &  " "  &  FORMAT(DATEVALUE(MAX('People  Registered'[DATE])) DD")  &  `SWITCH(DAY(MAX('People  Registered'[Last Refresh  Date])), 1,"st", 2, "nd", 3, "rd",  4, "th" , 21, "st", 22, "nd", 23, "rd", 24, "th" , 31, "st" )` &  " "  &  FORMAT(DATEVALUE(MAX( 'People  Registered'[Last Refresh  Date])),"MMM") &  " "  &  FORMAT(DATEVALUE(MAX('People  Registered'[Last Refresh  Date])),"YYYY")

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are able to add an ordinal number by using the following DAX:

```
VAR LatestDate = MAX( 'Time'[Date] )
VAR DayNum = DAY( LatestDate )
VAR Addition = MID("thstndrdth", MIN(9,2*RIGHT( DayNum )*(MOD( DayNum -11, 100) >2) +1), 2)
VAR Result = DayNum & Addition
RETURN Result
```

Hope that helps!

Rick